# Drawing table in Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, jtable, jframe

I am trying to programmatically set table in my Applet program. I tried the following code, it works fine. But, This is opening new window and then drawing the table. Can I have sample for drawing such table in the Applet view itself

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 Object rowData[][] = { 
         { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3" },
         { "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3" } 
 };
 Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };
 JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

 JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
 frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 frame.setSize(300, 150);
 frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec by your instructor, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: *"Can I have sample for drawing such table in the Applet view itself"* I forgot to add:-  SO is not a code generation machine.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a JFrame and adding your JScrollPane to that, you should extend JApplet and simply add your JScrollPane to that.

Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html

This is, of course, after taking into account the link Andrew Thompson already gave you.